# Displaying audio files from SD Card to Swipe View tabs - Android

Tags: android, audio, tabs, sd-card, swipeview

I found this example [ListView of audio files on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19546852/listview-of-audio-files-on-android) how to find audio files in SD Card. I didn't have chance to check if it works because it's not everything what I need. I need to display this audio files in Swipe View Tabs. There are tabs like: albums, authors, songs, genres and files. I want to have this songs segregate in tabs and have a possibility to play them. I just started learning Android so I have request for accurate explanation.

I hope I explained my problem enough clearly. Sorry for my English ;)

Greetings,
Agata

Comment: It's not realy a good question you posted, because we would write you your app if we answer it ;) But what you are looking for seems to be this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#viacontentresolver It describes the basics about quering audio media from the device. Because you can scan the sd card or something like that, because all the media is owned by different apps and you dont get access directly, but all media is accessable over the correct content provider.

Comment: `I didn't have chance to check if it works because it's not everything what I need.`. That does not matter. You should start with some basics first. While doing that you yourself can expand it in the direction of your needs. You are asking way to much now.

Comment: Don't worry. I'm not asking for writing my app ;) Thank's for that link. Maybe you know where can I read about adding found songs to list and displaying it in tabs?

Comment: _greenapps_, you may be wright that I'm not doing it in write order. I have this tabs but I don't know what to do next. As I said - I've just started learning Android ;)

Comment: After reading files from SDcard your next will be A ViewPager with fragments with all your tabs ( albums, authors, songs, genres ) then populate the data accordingly. :)

Comment: Ok, thanks for advices :) I hope you will help me again if I come across any problems ;)